# solr Search by first name and last name

Tags: search, solr

I have text field where information about user stores, including First name and last name.   For example: John Bell. When I search for "John" or "Bell" or "John Bell" It works ok.
But when I search by "Bell John" - search result is 0. Is it possible to solve this issue?    Schema configuration:

```
<field name="content" type="content_ws" indexed="true" stored="true" />

<fieldType name="content_ws" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="query">
    <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="index">
    <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

Comment: Did you include the double quotes in your search term?

Comment: the problem can be the positionIncrementGap, try to remove that parameter and check.

Comment: positionIncrementGap - Removed, nothing changed.
What fo you mean under "include the double quotes in your search term" ?

Answer (score 0):

By using [DisMax](http://lucidworks.lucidimagination.com/display/solr/The+DisMax+Query+Parser) query parser and setting [qs](http://lucidworks.lucidimagination.com/display/solr/The+DisMax+Query+Parser#TheDisMaxQueryParser-The%7B%7Bqs%7D%7D%28QueryPhraseSlop%29Parameter) parameter to the value greater than 2 will help you to find query in reverse order.

Query should be something like :

```
http://localhost:8993/solr/select?defType=dismax&q="Bell John"&qs=2
```

Answer (score 0):

With standard Query handler you can create queryies with the proximity parameter.

e.g. `q=content:"Bell John"~2` where 2 is the slop or the number of tokens apart.

When you search for John bell the words are at position and hence a proximity slop of Zero works. There is no change in position to create the same word as being searched upon.

However, when the query is `Bell John` the number of hops to create the words is 2

e.g.

```
Bell John - Query data  
Bell - One hop would bring Bell and John at the same position  
John  
John Bell - Second hop would recreate the indexed term.
```

Hence, for revered query the slop should be minimum 2 in this case.